# Unable to start bin/dse spark-sql. File not exception /tmp/hive

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I'am trying to run following command on DSE cassandra :-

```
dse$ bin/dse spark-sql
```

It gives following error :-

```
2018-05-24 16:59:41 [main] ERROR o.a.s.d.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper - Failed to start or submit Spark application - see details in the log file(s): /home/aditya/.spark-sql-shell.log
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver$.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:114) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.16.jar:2.0.2.16]
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.16.jar:2.0.2.16]
```

I'dont understand is this permission issue or something else but directory  has all permissions.

Thanks,

Comment: it talks about directory on DSEFS - run the `dse fs` and then do `ls -ls /tmp/hive` from there

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt - Thanks for your help , I was starting dse on normal mode . I had to start cassandra with -k to enable analytic mode. This solved my issue.

Comment: ah, yes - I thought that you're already started it in this mode...  What version of DSE you have, so I can file the bug against it?

Comment: DSE 5.1.7 linux 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. It was because I was not starting Cassandra in Analytic mode so if you face such problem make sure that you have started your Cassandra in Analytic mode by -

```
bin/dse cassandra -k
```

Thanks,